JavaFX - Different behavior of two GridPane in equal component hierarchy
I believe that the properties are defined equally in both. In the "correct.fxml" grid, if I add 1 row or 1 column, the respective ScrollPane's scrollbar appears. In the "wrong.fxml" grid this does not happen and I can't figure out why. Maybe I'm not seeing something different between them. Thanks for any help.
Correct.fxml

Wrong.fxml

Correct.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="429.0" 
prefWidth="761.0" stylesheets="@stylesheet.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <ScrollPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <content>
            <StackPane>
               <children>
                  <Pane StackPane.alignment="CENTER">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="1.0" vgap="1.0">
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                             <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>

Wrong.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="277.0" prefWidth="495.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="br.com.ablogic.crossword.MainViewController">
   <center>
      <ScrollPane fx:id="scpGrid" fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" 
focusTraversable="false" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <content>
            <StackPane fx:id="stkPane">
               <children>
                  <Pane fx:id="pane" StackPane.alignment="CENTER">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="1.0" vgap="1.0">
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" 
maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="40.0" minHeight="40.0" 
prefHeight="40.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                 </Pane>
              </children>
           </StackPane>
        </content>
     </ScrollPane>
  </center>
</BorderPane>


You have a BorderPane with only the centre occupied and that with a ScrollPane, that only has a StackPane that only has a Pane that only has a GridPane.  Surely you could achieve the same outcome with just a GridPane inside a ScrollPane?

@DaveB Hi Dave... Not mentioned in the problem description, but I insert an image into the StackPane by code. I need the Pane to be able to control the position of that image. Thank you.

Do you though?  If you are putting the image into the StackPane, then the Pane would have nothing to do with it. If the image is not overlapping the GridPane then a VBox or HBox would do the trick.

@DaveB If I can fine-tune the position with VBox or HBox, then that's fine, because that's what I can do with Pane. If I remove Pane, I'd only have nine positions to place the image with StackPane, if I'm not mistaken (Top.LEFT, Top.CENTER, etc.). Would there be any advantage in using them instead of Pane ?

In the "incorrect" version, you have fitToWidth="true" and fitToHeight="true" on the declaration of your ScrollPane.
This will force the scroll pane's content to fit the width of the viewport, and fit the height of the viewport, so that it can never be larger than the viewport and consequently scroll bars can never appear. See the documentation for these properties.
The "correct" version of your FXML doesn't have these settings, so the content will (usually) be sized to its preferred size, allowing the scroll bars to appear when necessary.
There are a lot of other anomalies in the code. For example, some of your column constraints have minWidth="40" maxWidth="40" prefWidth="100", which obviously makes no sense. It is typically not a good idea to hard-code these sizes (or, indeed, the size of the BorderPane, which is also different between your two versions) anyway: use percentWidth if you want to force all columns to be the same width. (There are other ways to achieve this too.) You also have completely redundant elements in the FXML in the Pane and StackPane surrounding the GridPane.

Perfect! Now it's working. All the things you found that are wrong are things I was trying to see if they would fix the problem and I forgot to remove or fix them. Thank you for explaining why the problem is happening and not just telling me how to fix it. This helps with learning. Thank you so much.
